# Various problem when upgrading from 20.04 to 22.04

Tags: upgrade, firefox, network-manager

I encountered several problems when upgrading from 20.04 to 22.04

First, I upgraded 20.04.
Something went wrong as I needed to boot then NetworkManager was not started.
When trying to start it, I got following message

```
NetworkManager: /usr/local/lib/libssh.so.4: version `LIBSSH_4_8_1' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurl-gnutls.so.4)
```

After a while, I found that libssh.so.4.8 was no more in /usr/local/lib/ but in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/

A symlink from /usr/local/lib/libssh.so.4 to /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssh.so.4.8.7 solved this problem.

I also lost all my personal profile in Firefox : bookmarks, extension, etc.
How to recover it ?

Now I try to upgrade to 22.04
Each time I try, I got the same message :

```
# do-release-upgrade 
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.
```

while I did (several times):  apt update; apt upgrade/full-upgrade/dist-upgrade

update-manager also claims that my distro is up to date, and proposes to upgrade to 22.04, then I got the same message than from do-release-upgrade

Any hints ?

Thanks a lot